# Acesso negado ao diretório

Tags: c#, instalador

Olá,

Eu tenho um projeto pequeno que esta funcionando perfeitamente. Após terminar a programação eu gerei um instalador usando o Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project.

O projeto instala corretamente mas quando tento usar, ele da acesso negado ao diretório.

Esta instalado dentro da pasta "Arquivo de Programa" e o programa manipula arquivos dentro desta pasta.

Então como faço para dar acesso de administrador dentro da pasta para o executável  da aplicação.

Normalmente acesso os arquivos assim:

```
var pathArqFinal = Environment.CurrentDirector + "\Filename.txt";
```

Muito obrigado.

Raimundo

Comment: Verifique se o problema ocorre quando você abre o aplicativo como administrador.

Comment: Se abrir como administrador não ocorre, executa perfeitamente. Como torno isto permanente, sem ter que ficar executando toda vez como administrador?

Comment: Tem que executar como administrador, se a pastar for arquivos de progama.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se fosse possivel editar o que esta dentro de arquivos de programa sem permissão elavada seria uma baita brecha de segurança, o que recomendo **no minimo** é você usar a pasta do nivel do usuário, mas para cada usuário será gerado um .txt (depende do que você já fez e precisa):

```
var pathArqFinal = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\Filename.txt";
```

> Conforme site da microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8
>
> O diretório que serve como um repositório comum para **dados específicos do aplicativo para o usuário móvel atual**. Um usuário móvel trabalha em mais de um computador em uma rede. O perfil de um usuário móvel é mantido em um servidor na rede e é carregado em um sistema quando o usuário faz logon.

Se for para todos usuário poderia usar o `CommonApplicationData`, assim:

```
var pathArqFinal = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\Filename.txt";
```

> O diretório que serve como um repositório comum para dados específicos do aplicativo que são usados por todos os usuários.

Desta forma vai ser um arquivo usado por todos, o problema disto é que precisará tomar cuidado com "condição corrida", pois múltiplas instâncias do aplicativo poderão se atrapalhar ao gravar.

Comment: No Windows tem também um diretório genérico "all users", não tem? Ou "public".

Comment: Eu achei que poderia dar permissão de adm apenas dentro da pasta da minha aplicação. De qualquer forma obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: @bfavaretto o texto da doc pt-br estava errado e me fez pensar que era para outra coisa, mesmo que o nome fosse semelhante ao do primeior enumerador citado na resposta, veja como esta: `O diretório que serve como um repositório comum para dados específicos do aplicativo que são usados por "todos os aplicativos".`, está todos aplicativos, então acessei em inglês para ter certeza https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8#System_Environment_SpecialFolder_CommonApplicationData, o certo era "by all users". Ajustei a resposta.